# Logging all commands run by PHP

Tags: php, logging

Somehow, one of our sites continues to be compromised.  Is there a way that I can log every command that PHP runs, either via system(), exec(), etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [override-function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.override-function.php), and [rename_function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rename-function.php) rewrite the system and exec commands, do a stack trace from there and log it to a file.

Comment: Is there a way to do this across an entire site, or just for a single page?